# Closed form for $\varepsilon$ satisfying $\frac{\alpha \cdot \pi}{n} = \sin^{-1}(\varepsilon) - \varepsilon \cdot \sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am looking for a closed form for $\varepsilon$ (or at least a close upper bound) in the following equation:

$$\frac{\alpha \cdot \pi}{n} = \sin^{-1}(\varepsilon) - \varepsilon \cdot \sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}$$

$n$ is a positive integer, $\alpha$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$ and also epsilon lies between $0$ and $1$.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve for $\varepsilon$ here?

Comment: There is no closed form solution. One can bound the RHS by $$\frac{2\epsilon^3}3\le\arcsin{(\epsilon)}-\epsilon\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}\le\frac{\pi\epsilon^3}2$$so that some bounds for $\epsilon$ are$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{2\alpha}n}\le\epsilon\le\sqrt[3]{\frac{3\alpha\pi}{2n}}$$

Comment: this is great, thank you

Comment: If you write $\varepsilon = \sin(x/2)$, you can express the problem as $$\frac{2\alpha \pi}{n} = x - \sin x$$ It remains a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) with no closed-form solution in general, but at least it's a little easier on the eyes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put ${\alpha\pi\over n}=:y$, and develop
$$f(\epsilon):=\arcsin\epsilon-\epsilon\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$$
into a series. This leads to the equation
$$y={2\over3}\epsilon^3+{1\over5}\epsilon^5+{3\over28}\epsilon^7+{5\over72}\epsilon^9+\ldots$$
Take the third root on both sides, and obtain
$$y^{1/3}=\left({2\over3}\right)^{1/3}\epsilon+c_3\epsilon^3+c_5\epsilon^5+c_7\epsilon^7+\ldots$$
with known $c_k$. When  $\sum_{j{\rm\  odd}} a_j z^j$ is  the inverse series of the RHS we obtain
$$\epsilon=\sum_{j{\rm\  odd}} a_j\>y^{j/3}=a_1y^{1/3}+a_3y+a_5 y^{5/3}+\ldots\ .$$
The first  $a_j$ can be calculated explicitly from the $c_k$; in particular $a_1=\left({3\over2}\right)^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the family of approximations

$$\text{LHS}=\frac\pi2(1-(1-\epsilon^2)^p),$$

which are invertible.

Below, $p=0.3$.

[image]

If you want more accuracy, you can use the $\epsilon$ given by the inverse formula

$$\sqrt{1-\sqrt[p]{1-\frac2\pi\text{LHS}}}$$

and apply one or two Newton's iterations

$$\epsilon\leftarrow \epsilon-\frac{\arcsin\epsilon-\epsilon\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}{\dfrac{2x^2}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}}.$$

Comment: I have to think a little bit about your answer, it looks very helpful. Just one question, how did you find this class of approximations? Can you link some literature or is this well known?

Comment: @Jannik: I plotted and observed, then generalized from an ellipse ($p=0.5$).

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve for $\varepsilon$ the equation

$$ \sin^{-1}(\varepsilon) - \varepsilon \cdot \sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}=k\qquad \qquad (k \leq 1)$$

In the same spirit as @Christian Blatter, expand the rhs as a Taylor series built around $\varepsilon=0$ and then use series reversion to get
$$\varepsilon=t-\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{a_n}{b_n}\, t^{2n+1} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3 k}{2}}$$ The first coefficients $(a_n,b_n)$ are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 10 \\
 2 & 19 & 1400 \\
 3 & 71 & 25200 \\
 4 & 17753 & 25872000 \\
 5 & 1312063 & 7207200000 \\
 6 & 647915701 & 12713500800000 \\
 7 & 846414193 & 57177120000000 \\
 8 & 1117493692636007 & 252957982717440000000 \\
 9 & 238748332703099 & 177399104762880000000 \\
 10 & 1290235740195299971 & 3096146537003520000000000 \\
 11 & 41076715548467264173 & 314173814535060480000000000 \\
 12 & 23475007072221552906288731 & 566078379029271972864000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$